# WooCommerce: display sale price with tax

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display the sales price of a product with taxes.

Actually I have the following code to show the regular price with taxes:

```
<?php echo woocommerce_price($product->get_price_including_tax()); ?>
```

But how must look the code for the sale price with taxes?

Comment: This is completely dependent on your business logic and what function is your server code exposing. Please be more specific about where you are exactly facing the issue.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: what does `woocommerce_price()` function do and what is the response of `$product->get_price_including_tax()`

Comment: This code displqys the regular price with tax. But I want to display the sale price with tax.